# Getting the conditions for equation to be solvable

Tags: equation-solving

I have a parametric equation to be solved, but I do not actually care for the solution. I only want to know the range of parameters for which the equation has a solution. Is there a way to get the conditions in *Mathematica*?

If I choose `MaxExtraConditions -> All` option in `Solve`, I get those `ConditionalExpression`s. So the only thing I need is to extract the conditions of these expressions.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [`SolveAlways`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveAlways.html).

Comment: Welcome! This question will be easier to answer and more useful for others if you add a working example / working code to show what you are working with.

Comment: There are such methods in mathematics. They are applied to equations dependent upon parameter(s), and the solution yields the value of the parameter or relation between several parameters, at which the real solution first emerges. They are efficient for some equations (such as, but not limited to, polynomial ones, for example), not for all though. Everything that works in mathematics can be implemented in Mathematica. I think, a good idea would be to post here your equation.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I have already found, what I am looking for.

```
Resolve[Exists[variables,F[variables,parameters]==0]]
```

gives, what I need.